# How to add admin_notices to wordpress Custom Menu Page

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to make a plugin and I used the following simple lines of code on my CUSTOM MENU page.

```
            <div id="message" class="updated below-h2 notice is-dismissible">
            <p><?php echo $message_string; ?></p>
            <button type="button" class="notice-dismiss"><span class="screen-reader-text">Dismiss this notice.</span></button>
        </div>
```

In this scenario, when I click on button, it does not have an attached click handler as do settings->general settings have on saving.

Then I used this function.

```
    function display_admin_notice() {
  ?>
  <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible"><p>The secret to success is to know something nobody else knows ~ Aristotle Onassis</p>

  </div>
  <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'display_admin_notice' );
```

what this did, is it displayed the admin notice on all the screen and there were following situations.

1. My Custom menu page "ADMIN NOTICE" does not have a click handler.
2. All other pages had a custom event handler and it worked on clicking.

I just got very little information on the net that admin notices are only loaded on default wordpress menus.

But I encountered a plugin big in size that is using the same lines of code to display the working clickable admin notices.

Can anybody suggest something?

Comment: When do you want the notice to show? On this custom page all the time, or when say a form is submitted?

Comment: @DanielJames I want to show it all the time on the CUSTOM MENU PAGE and when I click on close button, it should disappear. Just for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution from my problem. Those having problems using admin notices on your site may have this problem.

I de-registered jquery handle and enqueued my own jquery but with the handle **jquery-latest** . In order to load functionality dependent on jquery. Wordpress searches for the handle jquery. So make sure you use the same handle for loading jquery.

Correct way.

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery',  plugins_url( '/assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js',__FILE__ ), array(), '4.1.1', false);
```

Wrong way

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-latest',  plugins_url( '/assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js',__FILE__ ), array(), '4.1.1', false);
```